# KendoUi Grid setting pagesize in databound

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid which gets data and also font settings from the server.
The user has the option of either using scrolling or paging, but not both.

The problem is that when I set the font for the appropriate cells, that makes these rows bigger, so the rows no longer all fit inside the grid content area.

What I'm doing at the moment is all in the `dataBound` event:

- Set the styling.
- Given this styling, calculate how many rows can fit
  in the content.
- If the calculated row count doesn't match the
  `dataSource.pageSize`, set the dataSource.pageSize as this value.

The problem is that the pageSize method resets the grid (thereby calling dataBound (only sometimes?!)), removing the styling and also the dataBound becomes unbound somehow.

I have a jsfiddle which fails in a different manner but I think for the same reasons as my program, but if someone could tell me how to get it working I could apply the logic to my program.

http://jsfiddle.net/y6vMx/5/

Answer (score 0):

Why did you load the style when dataBound fires? Does the user have the option to change the style?

If I'll have to do something similar, I'll put styles to another event, like on page load or something similar.(the best way is to call it after you populate the grid)

I am also using kendo grid right now and I experience a lot of troubles..

Comment: The user can change the style on the server side, so it's pre-defined, no live changes. I can't set the styling for a cell until it is displayed, and that won't be until I reach the page that it is on; so I have to use the dataBound event for this. Then I get its height and use that info to set the pageSize.

Comment: So I've looked at this approach a bit and I've let the page size fit every item on load and then stored every row height, then set the `pageSize` to fit the data. But I still have the problem of going onto the next page I need to set the pageSize again as it may have changed... Know of any way to pre-define the size for each page or anything tedious like that?